# Using Bresenham's line algorithm to retrive all gps coordinates from a path

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude, bresenham

I have two pins on a map, and I need to check if they intersect with each other.
Each pin has the start coordinates and end coordinates (with 20km distance between the start and the end). I'm think on using the Bresenham's line algorithm to storage all the coordinates between the start and the end of each pin and proceed to check if there are coordinates in commun with the other pin on the map. If that happens it means that they intersect.
I'm not sure if this is the easiest approach to check the intersection between two paths. Does anyone know if this method will work or if there is an easier one?

Comment: the intersect is perform between two lines or rectangle or circle or any two shapes.But not in between two points

Comment: But I was thinking that using the start point and the end point they would be connected right? They'll an "imaginary line" between them

Comment: no when two points lat  and long same ,then we can tell they are intersected each other.Exam, when two line intersect there two points lat and long same

Comment: Exactly that's what I was thinking. Do this algorithm for the two pins, because according to the Bresenham's algorithm it only uses the start coordinate and the end coordinate. And after saving all th coordinates od each pin (from start to finish) I would check if they have any coordinates in commun